# Making a new product type in wordpress (woocommerce) based on simple product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i am trying to make a new product type, the problem is that right now it is based on $product, which seem to make it not sellable or something, cause on the product page i get no add to cart, and on admin product page i get no general tab with prices and no inventory tab.

i added the code i have in my theme/functions.php

How can i make this custom type product sellable :/

thanks

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_test_product_type' );

function register_test_product_type() {

  class WC_Product_Test_Product extends WC_Product {

    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'test_product';
    parent::__construct( $simple_product );
    }
  }
}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_test_product_type' );

function add_test_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'test' ] = __( 'Test product', 'test_product' );

    return $types;  
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'test_product_tab' );

function test_product_tab( $tabs) {

    $tabs['test'] = array(
      'label'    => __( 'Tests', 'test_product' ),
      'target' => 'test_product_options',
      'class'  => 'show_if_test_product',
     );
    return $tabs;
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_test_product_settings' );

function save_test_product_settings( $post_id ){

    $test_product_info = $_POST['test_product_info'];

    if( !empty( $test_product_info ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'test_product_info', esc_attr( $test_product_info ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'test_product_front' );

function test_product_front () {
    global $product;

    if ( 'test' == $product->get_type() ) {      
       echo( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'test_product_info' )[0] );

  }
}

function remove_linked_products($tabs){
    unset($tabs['shipping']);
    return($tabs);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);
```

new code is saving fine and all but the price from woocommerce if giving me this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_price() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-content\themes\crane\functions.php:1488 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(286): demo_product_tab_product_tab_content('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-includes\plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\views\html-product-data-panel.php(53): do_action('woocommerce_pro...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\admin\meta-boxes\class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php(35): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-admin\includes\template.php(1306): WC_Meta_Box_Product_Data::output(Object(WP_Post), Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php(638): do_meta_boxes(Object(WP_Screen), 'normal', Object(WP_Post)) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp in C:\xampp\htdocs\fineland\wp-content\themes\crane\functions.php on line 1488
```

new code

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_demo_product_type' );
function register_demo_product_type() {
    class WC_Product_Demo extends WC_Product {       
    public function __construct( $product ) {
    $this->product_type = 'demo';
    parent::__construct( $product );
    }
  }
}

add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'add_demo_product_type' );
function add_demo_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'demo' ] = __( 'Demo product', 'dm_product' );
    return $types;  
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'demo_product_tab' );
function demo_product_tab( $tabs) {

    $tabs['demo'] = array(
      'label'    => __( 'Test', 'dm_product' ),
      'target' => 'demo_product_options',
      'class'  => 'show_if_demo_product',
     );
    unset($tabs['shipping']);
    return $tabs;
}

global $product;
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 'demo_product_tab_product_tab_content' );
function demo_product_tab_product_tab_content() {

 ?><div id='demo_product_options' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'><?php
 ?><div class='options_group'><?php
    $products;             
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
    array(
      'id'        => '_regular_price',
      'value'     => $product->get_price( 'edit' ),
      'label'     => __( 'Regular price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
      'data_type' => 'price',
    )
    );
 ?></div>
 </div><?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_demo_product_settings' );  
function save_demo_product_settings( $post_id ){

    $_regular_price = $_POST['_regular_price'];

    if( !empty( $_regular_price ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', esc_attr( $_regular_price ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'demo_product_front' );
function demo_product_front () {
    global $product;

    if ( 'demo' == $product->get_type() ) {      
       echo( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price' )[0] );

  }
}
```

Comment: This is much more complicated than that… Your custom product type need to extend `WC_Product` Class and many more others things.

Answer (score 0):

Seems likely that you need to add in a few variables. make sure to declare price, tax_status, manage_stock, stock_quantity, stock_status. That should get you going for simple products but make sure if you change the product type to ensure you declare all the other settings appropriate.

For the full product data schema take a look here and ensure you have all required entries for your local install settings. https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Product-Data-Schema

Answer (score 0):

"add to cart" option. is added by this action:

> 'woocommerce_<your_custom_product_type>_add_to_cart'

that is separate for each product type.

for example you can add "simple" product "add to cart" button for product type "demo" by this code

```
add_action('woocommerce_demo_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart');
```

- note:
  `woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart()` is a function provided by woocommerce